Do error-categories have static addresses?
If I throw a system_error, is the error_category-object copied or taken as a reference so that both addresses in the following code are always the same ?
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    try
    {
        cout << &system_category() << endl;
        throw system_error( 0, system_category(), "" );
    }
    catch( system_error &se )
    {
        cout << &se.code().category() << endl;
    };
}

For my platform both addreses are the same:
00007FF609AC5010
00007FF609AC5010


First line here : Obtains a reference to the static error category object.

@FrançoisAndrieux: Thanks and I should have thought that myself because I saw that error_cateogory-s aren't copyable.

Again from cppreference: "The objects of error category classes are treated as singletons, passed by reference."

@FrançoisAndrieux cpp reference is a reference, not a standard.

@FrançoisAndrieux I mean, it isn't convincing, because it might be citing compiler behavior and not the standard.  The OP has already checked their compiler, so saying "someone else who checked their compiler also found this to be true" isn't a huge improvement.  From the wording, it definitely isn't quoting the standard ("static object" in that sense isn't how standardese is phrased)

@Yakk-AdamNevraumont I see, I misunderstood the intent of your comment. I generally believe cppreference until shown to be incorrect. It is very heavily relied upon and false information doesn't tend to survive long there. In this particular case the page specifically mentions how it works on Windows vs POSIX increasing my confidence that this information isn't simply the observed behaviour of a single user.

Yes, the addresses are guaranteed to be the same. Actually, error_category objects are non-copyable.
Internally, system_error stores a error_code, and the error_code behaves as if it stores a pointer to the associated error_category ([syserr.errcode]).
[syserr.errcat.objects]:

All calls to [system_category] shall return references to the same object.

